# how to retrieve contact number according to name in spinner

Tags: android

i am new in android development.my application want contact number according to name that i have to select from spinner i use android 1.6.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) 

            {

                String name,phoneNumber;
                name=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                String[] projection1 = new String[]{
                        People._ID,People.NAME,People.NUMBER
                     };         
                Cursor cur=getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection1,People.NAME+"="+name , null, null);               

                phoneNumber=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "number="+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               /* cur.moveToFirst();
                     if(cur.moveToFirst())
                     {
                         do
                         {



                         }while(cur.moveToNext());

                     }*/
            }
```

Thanks in advance
Regards:
Arpit

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete code try this

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if(name.equals(sentTo)){
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null);

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        for(int i=0;i<pCur.getColumnCount();i++)
                            number = pCur.getString(i);

                    } 
                    pCur.close();
                    pCur = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

give permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

create modal class

```
public class ContactSave {

    String name;
    String number;

    public ContactSave(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", number='" + number + '\'';
    }
}
```

write your code in MainActivity

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<ContactSave> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        readAllContact();

    }


    private void readAllContact() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor cursor = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        arrayList.add(new ContactSave(name, phoneNo));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<ContactSave> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ContactSave>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
                    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```